# Сложная синтаксическая конструкция (1)

Tags: синтаксис

Можно ли от нескольких главных предложений, которые связаны бессоюзной связью, задать вопрос к одной придаточной части, если они с ней все взаимосвязаны?

Как только Валентина опустилась на сено, так (никогда не забыть мне этого) блаженное выражение разбилось по её лицу, глаза закрылись, голова покачнулась, и вся она обмякла, крепко-накрепко уснув

Comment: Как только Валентина опустилась на сено, так (никогда не забыть мне этого) блаженное выражение разбилось по её лицу, глаза закрылись, голова покачнулась, и вся она обмякла, крепко-накрепко уснув.

Comment: Добавьте это предложение в вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Как только Валентина опустилась на сено, так (никогда не забыть мне этого) блаженное выражение раз**л**илось по её лицу, глаза закрылись, голова покачнулась, и вся она обмякла, крепко-накрепко уснув.*

Здесь действительно общее придаточное для части ***так (...)блаженное выражение разлилось по её лицу, глаза закрылись, голова покачнулась***, а вот простое предложение  ***вся она обмякла, крепко-накрепко уснув*** связано со всей первой частью причинно-следственными связями, поэтому перед союзом **И** стоит запятая.

Смысл: Когда Валентина опустилась на сено, блаженное выражение разлилось по её лицу, глаза закрылись, голова покачнулась - и как следствие всего этого, она уснула.

У Розенталя: Как только сапёры перетащили машину на другую сторону и поставили на шоссе, Зубенко дал газ, и грузовик преспокойно поехал дальше (Медв.) — последнее предложение указывает на общее следствие.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133